# Turning simple Excel file into CartoDB map?

Tags: carto, excel

I have Field 6 in my Excel sheet as a column of Zip Codes.

How do I get them to show up on the map using CartoDB?

My map continues to be blank.

Comment: http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/how_to_georeference/ see "By postal code"

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @toms, you can find in the CartoDB documentation a step-by-step guide about [how to geocode your data](http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/how_to_georeference/). Basically, click on the Edit buttom at the top of the Dataset View. Then, click on Georeference. Select "By postal code". And finally, select the field in which you have stored postal codes (Field 6) and choose the country your postal codes are located. Continue.